Why doesn't my unit test for kotlin flow fail?
I would have expected this test to fail:
 @Test
fun testFlowFailure() = runTest {
    val flow = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    val job = launch {
        flow.collect {
            if (it == 1) {
                fail()
                latch.countDown()
            }
        }
    }
    flow.emit(1)
    latch.await()
    job.cancelAndJoin()
}

I do get the expected failure if I do countDown before fail(), so I assume that the exception is postponed until the join call. How can I change the code so it fails immediately inside the collect?

CountDownLatch is an utility for Java and threading, it is not compatible with coroutines. It awaits by blocking the thread, which is not allowed in coroutines, and it makes coroutines unresponsive. Frankly speaking, I'm not sure how it could work for you after moving latch.countDown() before fail(). I think it should result in a deadlock in both cases.
I believe coroutines framework doesn't provide a direct equivalent of CountDownLatch. Depending on your case you can use CompletableDeferred, Semaphore or Channel, for example:
@Test
fun testFlowFailure() = runTest {
    val flow = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val deferred = CompletableDeferred<Unit>()
    val job = launch {
        flow.collect {
            if (it == 1) {
                fail()
                deferred.complete(Unit)
            }
        }
    }
    flow.emit(1)
    deferred.await()
    job.cancelAndJoin()
}


The issue is not really with the countDownLatch itself, but the fact that the fail will never be logged if job.cancelAndJoin() is not called. (However, I do agree that your suggestion to use CompletableDeferred over a CountDownLatch would be preferable.)

I suspected there might be something else going on here, because again, it felt we should get a deadlock anyway, no matter if we call fail or not. But to be honest, from your provided code I'm not exactly sure what you try to test, so it's hard to tell what's the best approach.

Thanks to the answer by @broot, I approached the issue from another direction.
This code fulfills my needs - asserting a condition for a flow and gives the option the leave the collect at an end condition:
    @Test
    fun testFlowFailure() = runTest {
        val flow = MutableStateFlow(0)
        val job = async {
            flow.collect {
                when(it) {
                    1 -> cancel()
                    2 -> fail()
                    else -> {}
                }
            }
        }
        flow.emit(2)
        job.join()
    }

Emitting 1 cancels the job, emitting 2 fails.
Please comment if there are any drawbacks.
